# Setting up maven dependency for SQL Server 

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, maven

I am developing a portlet where I have Hibernate access to SQL Server database. I set up **maven dependencies** for it and try to find out SQL Server connector on the same way I know MySql has it.

Still my Google-search gives only Mysql if I search for SQL Server connector. What is the right **maven dependency** value?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1074869/521799

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Download the driver JAR from the link provided by Olaf and [add it to your local Maven repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) with;

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

Then add it to your project with;

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
  <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The release notes for the version linked from Olaf's answer state that it's "Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server". So I would use "-Dversion=4.0" in the mvn install.

Comment: I ran into an issue: "no POM in this directory" The solution to that can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348459/maven-3-0-5-command-error-the-goal-you-specified-requires-a-project-to-execute

Comment: sourceforge jtds is your answer

Comment: You can download the jar here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqljdbc420jar.htm

Comment: Would downloading and adding it to the local maven repo not lead to a tight coupling with the development machine you are building your app on? I mean if the same project is tried to be build on a different machine, it would not find the jar in the local repo. Wouldn't it be good to add it to the project so that its available on VCS?

Comment: Check this as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207842/add-external-library-jar-to-spring-boot-jar-internal-lib

Answer (score 74):

#### Answer for the "new" and "cool" Microsoft.

Yay, SQL Server driver now under MIT license on

- GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc
- Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmssql-jdbc

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Answer for the "old" Microsoft:

For my use-case (integration testing) it was sufficient to use a system scope for the JDBC driver's dependency as such:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

That way, I could put the JDBC driver into local version control. No need to have each developer manually set stuff up in their own repositories.

I took inspiration from [this answer to another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9779295/521799) and [I've also blogged about it here](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/02/how-to-integrate-commercial-third-party-artefacts-into-your-maven-build/).

Comment: If it's possible, I think it is better to upload the JAR on the local maven repository (Nexus)

Comment: @mcoolive: It definitely is better, mostly. But sometimes, it's just easier (and still appropriate) to do a quick-and-dirty job.

Comment: This answer is outdated compared to Touzery's updated answer.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: Well, I updated my answer even before Touzery. In fact, Touzery's answer is more outdated, because it still refernces a library from sourceforge. *sourceforge*!!

Comment: Don't forget to exclude azure-keyvault dependencies for new opensourced driver for versions <6.1.4.
6.1.3 and down to 6.1.0.jre7 add ridiculous amount of transitive dependencies.
gladly, they fixed it.

Comment: @MikhailFedorov: My solution worked for me. Feel free to add your own answer (or even a question / answer pair) that shows how to solve this, would be great for the community.

Answer (score 17):

There is also an alternative: you could use the open-source jTDS driver for MS-SQL Server, which is compatible although not made by Microsoft.
For that driver, there is a maven artifact that you can use:

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

From http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE** nov 2016, Microsoft now published its MSSQL JDBC driver [on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc) and it's also available on maven now:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: For Java 1.6 : I am guessing the higher versions are for 1.7..
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
 <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>

Comment: note that there were no releases of JTDS since 2013 so that may be bad advice nowadays...

Comment: The jtds driver had problems with ssl in java 8 (patched but not released) so we switched to sqljdbc4

Answer (score 9):

I believe you are looking for the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724

Comment: Yes, this is the one. I would like to load it through maven, so this was not actually answer to my question. So, first one giving that will get my tick for his/her answer!

Comment: Looks like there are some disagreements between Maven and Microsoft folks regarding licensing and redistribution of the JDBC driver: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2010/03/02/microsoft-sql-server-jdbc-3-0-ctp-release-announcement.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with the answers above. sqljdbc4.jar is not distributed with under a public license which is why it is difficult to include it in a jar for runtime and distribution. See my answer below for more details and a much better solution. Your life will become much easier as mine did once I found this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30111956/3368958

Answer (score 2):

Even after installing the sqlserver jar, my maven was trying to fetch the dependecy from maven repository. I then, provided my pom the repository of my local machine and it works fine after that...might be of help for someone.

```
    <repository>
        <id>local</id>
        <name>local</name>
        <url>file://C:/Users/mywindows/.m2/repository</url>
    </repository>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hynnet</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqljdbc4-chs</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2206.100</version>
</dependency>
```

This worked for me(if you use maven)

https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.hynnet/sqljdbc4-chs/4.0.2206.100/jar

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Microsoft has published some their drivers to maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```