# maven dependency for sqlserver2010?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, maven

I am using maven. i am using sqlserver2010 database. what is the corresponding maven dependency to use com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver ? Also in which repository i can find it to get downloaded?

Thanks!

Comment: Related to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942407/setting-up-maven-dependency-for-sql-server). Looks like you will need to manually install...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the one.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
   <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

download the jar from [here.](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

To add to the repository.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=3.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

**UPDATED** The new dependency edited here.

Comment: i added this but this is not there in maven central repository.

Comment: added the command to add this dependency to your repository and then add the dependency in your pom.

Comment: Also you need to download the jar file from the link provided in my updated answer. :-)

Comment: where should i execute the command? in command prompt do i need to be inside .m2 and run the command? Thanks!

Comment: if you have added M2_HOME in your env variables then you can run from any place in your folder system. Otherwise you need to be in the bin folder of your maven installation directory.

Comment: i tried but i am getting below error.[INFO] Error installing artifact 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar': Error i
nstalling artifact: File C:\apache-maven-2.1.0\bin\sqljdbc4.jar does not exist

Comment: you need to copy and paste the download jar files from the link I provided in asnwer to the path you are getting error.

Comment: i have placed the sqljdbc4-3.0 jar in bin directory and run the command but of no use...

Comment: you have to change the name of jar file in the command. Are you using as it is I have placed in the answer??

Answer (score 2):

Download official driver and install it into your private, internal repository (like Nexus) as 3rd party stuff or into local repo (if you don't use Nexus) by `mvn install:install-file ...`.

Alternatively use [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) and get the artifact from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```