# Specified JDBC Driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" class not found

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I try to create simple application for testing hibernate. I use ms sql server as database

I download sqljdbc4 from microsoft official site and add to build path of my sts(eclipse):
[image]

And it locates on maven dependencies

When I invoke my application I saw:

```
SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" class not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at logic.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:22)
    at logic.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at logic.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" class not found
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782)
    at logic.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class ["com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:104)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:99)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
    ... 17 more
```

I don't understand the cause if this messages. If in code I write:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

and type ctrl+left mouse click I saw ![enter image description here][2]

Therefore I can made output, that this class exists, but hibernate doesn't see its.

Can you help me?

**UPDATE**

> How do you invoke your application?

I have so class:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Prepod prepod = new Prepod();
        Student student = new Student();
        prepod.getStudents().add(student);
        student.getPrepods().add(prepod);

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(student);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

and so:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            // Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(
            // "C:\\Users\\Nikolay_Tkachev\\workspace\\hiberTest\\src\\logic\\hibernate.cfg.xml");
            // return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                    .configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

right click for Main.java -> run as->java Application

**UPDATE 2**

project structure:

![enter image description here][3]

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hiberTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hiberTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myTest</name>
    <description>description</description>
    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
            <version>${mysql.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**UPDATE FOR Vinay**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

...
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\.m2> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc4-3.0.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactI
d=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=3.0 -Dpackaging=jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\.m2\sqljdbc4-3.0.jar to C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sql
server\sqljdbc4\3.0\sqljdbc4-3.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.686s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 11 17:05:35 MSK 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/90M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\.m2>cd C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\mavenHibernateTest

C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\mavenHibernateTest>mvn eclipse:eclipse
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for hiberTest:hiberTest:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar ->
 version 4.0.1.Final vs 4.1.4.Final @ line 45, column 15
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) @ hiberTest >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) @ hiberTest <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) @ hiberTest ---
[INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: null
[INFO] Adding default classpath container: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER
[INFO] File C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\mavenHibernateTest\.project already exists.
       Additional settings will be preserved, run mvn eclipse:clean if you want old settings to be removed.
[INFO] Wrote Eclipse project for "hiberTest" to C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\mavenHibernateTest.
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.061s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 11 17:07:20 MSK 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/113M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\mavenHibernateTest>
```

But I have old problems(((

**UPDATE**

```
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\mavenHibernateTest>
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\mavenHibernateTest>mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="logic.Main"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for hiberTest:hiberTest:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar ->
 version 4.0.1.Final vs 4.1.4.Final @ line 45, column 15
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ hiberTest >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ hiberTest <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ hiberTest ---
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver "
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" class not found
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at logic.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
        at logic.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
        at logic.Main.main(Main.java:12)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc
.SQLServerDriver" class not found
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnec
tionProviderImpl.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159
)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159
)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2277)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2273)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782)
        at logic.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class ["com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc
.SQLServerDriver"]
        at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnec
tionProviderImpl.java:104)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

        at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:99)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
        ... 23 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.403s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 11 17:14:07 MSK 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/115M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project hiberTest: An excepti
on occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: ExceptionInInitializerError: Specified JDBC Driv
er "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" class not found: Unable to load class ["com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLSe
rverDriver"]: Could not load requested class : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\mavenHibernateTe
```

st>

**content sqljdbc.jar**
[image: content sqljdbc.jar:]

### **Solution**:

*WRONG*:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerD‌​river"</property>
```

*RIGHT:*

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerD‌​river</property>
```

Comment: How do you invoke your application? If you use an eclipse run configuration, it should work (but still show us, how). However, if you use maven to run it or you use maven to package it and run it manuallay afterwards, the JAR file will not be in the class path.

Comment: just in case I added jar to build path and to maven dependencies

Comment: You should list only one dependency. Remove the single build path entry, if it is already part of the Maven dependencies. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: I deleted, But i see old exception

Comment: Hmm ... difficult to solve remotely. Maybe you could give me (us) more details: Project structure (directories, files, ...), path and content of the library folder in the Maven repository (only for the MS SQL driver), content of the pom.xml, content of the Hibernate configuration file, and whatever you consider to be of importance. I know, that not all of this is necessary, but it might help.

Comment: Additionally: Please try to run via Maven. Open a command prompt, change to you project directory (the one containing the pom.xml), then run the command mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="my.pkg.Main". Of course, adjust the package. What is the outcome?

Comment: updated topic for this way

Comment: Last try: Please try to get rid of the warning mentioning the Hibernate version mismatch. Maybe that is your problem. Otherwise, I really can't see a problem in your configuration. Seems to be ok. Strange ...

Comment: Ah! Another idea: Could you please have a look into the content of the JAR file? Post it. Maybe this JAR is not a library JAR, but a simple ZIP file containing the real library JAR. I had this behavior with many other libraries, too.

Comment: <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property> - error using " " "

Comment: Instead of flagging or commenting, why don't you write up your conclusions as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

very simple mistake:

**Solution**:

*WRONG*:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"</property>
```

*RIGHT:*

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
```

It is very funny)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add sqljdbc driver as maven dependency. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942407/setting-up-maven-dependency-for-sql-server)
2. Invoke mvn eclipse:eclipse
3. Run your application

I am pretty sure this will solve your problem.

Comment: this variant doesn't work in my situation. I added info to topic.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet works well for connecting and querying database in Microsoft SQL SERVER. Please note that Microsoft does not make jar file 'sqljdbc42.jar'(which is jdbc driver) available on any online repo like MavenCentral(). Therefore, you would need to download this jar from Microsoft's website and save in project workspace directory. Download 'sqljdbc_4.2.6420.100_enu.exe'

Unzip the downloaded file and go to Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.2 for SQL Server-->sqljdbc_4.2-->enu. Here you will see the file sqljdbc42.jar. Copy the file into project workspace. I copied into dir name 'lib'.

```
        repositories {
            flatDir name: 'localRepository', dirs: 'lib'
        }
        configurations {
            driver
        }
        dependencies {
            driver group: 'sql', name: 'sqljdbc42', version:''
        }


        URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader
        configurations.driver.each { File file ->
            loader.addURL(file.toURL())
        }

        task connectToCoreDb << {
            def props = [user: 'sa', password: 'shock', allowMultiQueries: 'true'] as Properties
            def connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://cpt-op-01-db1:1433;databaseName=buds"
            def driver = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
            def sql = Sql.newInstance(connectionUrl, props, driver)
            sql.eachRow('SELECT name, alias, expiry_date FROM [buds].[dbo].[obj_keystore] ) { row ->
                println "$row.name $row.alias $row.expiry_date"
            }
            logger.info "Closing connection..."
            sql.close()
        }
```