# Missing artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0

Tags: sql-server, spring, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to add MS SQL driver dependency in my POM.xml file and the following is the dependency.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but I get this exception

> Missing artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0

I really don't understand the issue.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Microsoft now provide this artifact in maven central. See @nirmal's answer for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41149866/1570834

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The issue is that Maven can't find this artifact in any of the configured [maven repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html).

Unfortunately Microsoft doesn't make this artifact available via any maven repository. You need to download the jar from the [Microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774), and then manually install it into your local maven repository.

You can do this with the following maven command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then next time you run maven on your POM it will find the artifact.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i get this when i run the command `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4
:install-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The specified file 'C:\Us
ers\anthony\sqljdbc4.jar' not exists -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Make sure sqljdbc4.jar is places in directory you are running command in, otherwise provide full path explicitly.

Comment: @Antony, as Sergey says, you need to either run the maven command (as given in my answer) from the same location where you downloaded the sqljdbc4.jar to or provide the full path to the file `-Dfile=C:\Users\anthony\Downloads\sqljdbc4.jar` for example.

Comment: after installing sqljdbc4.jar as @DB5 said , It still gives me the same error when I run mvn package in my project , any thoughts on that? Where does it actually gets installed ? can I see a list of locally installed jars from mvn?

Comment: I got an error -  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The artifact information is incomplete or not valid:
[ERROR] [0]  'packaging' is missing.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]                 which was resolved by adding         -Dpackaging=jar to the command

Comment: see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41149866/306538) below, microsoft (as of nov 2016) added this jdbc driver to maven central

Comment: Microsoft advices the last version which has jdbc42.jar not jdbc4.jar. If you want to keep on jdbc4.jar then you shoul go: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54629

Comment: i find the sqljdbc4.jar here: https://osdn.net/frs/g_redir.php?m=tuna&f=id2d%2Fjdbc+drivers%2Fsqljdbc4.jar

Answer (score 85):

Microsoft recently [open sourced their jdbc driver](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2016/11/17/open-source-jdbc-maven/).

You can now find the driver on maven central:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

or for java 7:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I've tried making this work for hours and found out that version 7.4.1 doesn't load a driver for me by version 7.0.0 does. Do you know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 30):

I had the similar problem and solved it by doing following.

- Download sqljdbc4.jar from the Microsoft website to your local machine.
- Right click on Project-->Import-->Maven-->Install or deploy an artifact to a Maven repository as shown below.

[image]

* Next-->Fill the following details
`Artifact file:`
 path of the jar you downloaded (Ex: E:\lib\sqljdbc4.jar in my case)  
`Group Id:` com.microsoft.sqlserver
`Artifact Id:` sqljdbc4
`Version:` 4.0
[image]

- Then Refresh/clean the project.

  **Thank you!**

Comment: still  i am getting this issue

Comment: Awesome!!! But I had to refresh the project via Project-->right click-->maven-->Update Project...

Answer (score 12):

You can also create a project repository. It's useful if more developers are working on the same project, and the library must be included in the project.

- First, create a repository structure in your project's lib directory, and then copy the library into it. The library must have following name-format: `<artifactId>-<version>.jar`

  `<your_project_dir>/lib/com/microsoft/sqlserver/<artifactId>/<version>/`
- Create pom file next to the library file, and put following information into it:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <modelVersion>4.2.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
       <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
       <version>4.2</version>
   </project>
  ```
- At this point, you should have this directory structure:

  `<your_project_dir>/lib/com/microsoft/sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.2/sqljdbc4-4.2.jar`
  `<your_project_dir>/lib/com/microsoft/sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.2/sqljdbc4-4.2.pom`
- Go to your project's pom file and add new repository:

  ```
  <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>Project repository</id>
           <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
  ```
- Finally, add a dependency on the library:

  ```
  <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
           <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
           <version>4.2</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
  ```

**Update 2017-03-04**

It seems like the library can be obtained from publicly available repository. @see nirmal's and Jacek Grzelaczyk's answers for more details.

**Update 2020-11-04**

Currently Maven has a convenient target `install` which allow you to deploy an existing package into a project / file repository without the need of creating POM files manually. It will generate those files for you.

```sh
mvn install:install-file \
    -Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar \
    -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver \
    -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 \
    -Dversion=4.2 \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -DlocalRepositoryPath=${your_project_dir}/lib
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, IMHO. Despite putting a binary into the git repository, it is a fire and forget solution. There is no need for further instruction on how to deploy the driver to each developer local repository (or searching StackOverflow for help).

Comment: @Ipacheco is correct, this should indeed be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

The above answer only adds the sqljdbc4.jar to the **local** repository. As a result, when creating the final project jar for distribution,  sqljdbc4 will again be missing as was indicated in the comment by @Tony regarding runtime error.

Microsoft (and Oracle and other third party providers) restrict the distribution of their software as per the ENU/EULA. Therefore those software modules do not get added in Maven produced jars for distribution. There are hacks to get around it (such as providing the location of the 3rd party jar file at runtime), but as a developer you must be careful about violating the licensing.

**A better approach for jdbc connectors/drivers is to use [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)**, which is compatible to most DBMS's, more reliable, faster (as per benchmarks), and distributed under GNU license. It will make your life much easier to use this than trying to pound the square peg into the round hole following any of the other techniques above.

Comment: oh man jtds saved my day, configuring sqljdbc4 with gradle is some pain the a*s

Comment: Only thing is that jTDS doesn't support the same functionality as Microsoft's driver. For example, batch update.

Comment: it is unfortunate that jTDS does not support the datetime2 data type. seems my choices are to roll my own datetime2-to-java-date method, or go through a lot of hoops getting the microsoft driver to work.

Comment: As of 2017, the driver has not been updated to JDBC4 and is pretty much dead, does not work with HikariCP and more modern conn pools.

Answer (score 2):

just add

```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
       <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
       <version>4.0</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
     </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For self-containing Maven project I usually installing all external jar dependencies into project's repository. For SQL Server JDBC driver you can do:

- download JDBC driver from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11774
- create folder `local-repo` in your Maven project
- temporary copy `sqljdbc42.jar` into `local-repo` folder
- in `local-repo` folder run `mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=sqljdbc42.jar -DartifactId=sqljdbc42 -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=6.0.7507.100 -Durl=file://.` to deploy JAR into local repository (stored together with your code in SCM)
- `sqljdbc42.jar` and downloaded files can be deleted
- modify your's `pom.xml` and add reference to project's local repository:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>parent-local-repository</id>
            <name>Parent Local repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>file://${basedir}/local-repo</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Now you can run your project everywhere without any additional configurations or installations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having some issue when including dependency for 6.1.0.jre7 from @nirmals answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41149866/1570834, in your pom with commons-codec/ azure-keyvault I prefer going with this:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
       <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
       <version>6.2.2.jre7</version>                
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not too hard. I have not read the license yet.  However I have proven this works.  You can copy sqljdbc4 jar file to a network share or local directory.  Your build.gradle should look like this :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
//apply plugin: 'maven'
//apply plugin: 'enhance'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

//library versions
def hibernateVersion='4.3.10.Final'
def microsoftSQLServerJDBCLibVersion='4.0'
def springVersion='2.5.6'

def log4jVersion='1.2.16'
def jbossejbapiVersion='3.0.0.GA'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{url "file://Sharedir/releases"}
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hibernateVersion"
    compile "com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:$microsoftSQLServerJDBCLibVersion"
}

task showMeCache << {
    configurations.compile.each { println it }
}
```

under the sharedir/releases directory, I have directory similar to maven structure which is \sharedir\releases\com\microsoft\sqlserver\sqljdbc4\4.0\sqljdbc4-4.0.jar

good luck.

David Yen

Answer (score 0):

You can use another driver

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and in xml

```
    <bean id="idNameDb" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[ip]:1433;DatabaseName=[name]" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `com.microsoft.sqlserver` package on Maven now only has version 6.0 as the lowest version JDBC. So you need try another `groupId` Maven which has JDBC version 4.0.

I recommend this; it works for me. I'm using SQL Server 2012 and Java 8.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And a config properties file like:

```
jdbc.driverClassName = net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

jdbc.url = jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=YourDB;encrypt=true;trustserverCertificate=true
```

Answer (score 0):

For the old JDBC jars artifacts:

To, [**install**] 3rd party JARs to [**local**] repo:

```
# `mvn install:install-file`    to install  a custom file `install-file` [artifact] into the local repo
# For more info about (maven-deploy-plugin) parameters:
# https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html
# https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

# [install > local repo] 
# Example: com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:pom:3.0
groupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver
artifactId=sqljdbc4
version=3.0
packaging=jar
file=/...path_to_jar.../sqljdbc4-3.0.jar
pomFile=/...path_to_pom.../sqljdbc4-3.0.pom
localRepositoryPath=/Users/~/.m2/repository


mvn install:install-file \
    -DgroupId=$groupId \
    -DartifactId=$artifactId \
    -Dversion=$version \
    -Dpackaging=$packaging \
    -Dfile=$file \
    -DpomFile=$pomFile \
    -DlocalRepositoryPath=$localRepositoryPath
```

To, [**deploy**] 3rd party JARs to [**remote**] repo:

```
# `mvn deploy:deploy-file`      to deploy   a custom file `deploy-file` [artifact] to the remote repo
# For more info about (maven-install-plugin) parameters:
# https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html
# https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

# [deploy > remote repo] 
# Example: com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:pom:3.0
groupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver
artifactId=sqljdbc4
version=3.0
packaging=jar
file=/...path_to_jar.../sqljdbc4-3.0.jar
pomFile=/...path_to_pom.../sqljdbc4-3.0.pom
createChecksum=true
repositoryId=your_company-3rdparty-repo
url=https://nexus.your_company.com/content/repositories/thirdparty

mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -DgroupId=$groupId \
    -DartifactId=$artifactId \
    -Dversion=$version \
    -Dpackaging=$packaging \
    -Dfile=$file \
    -DpomFile=$pomFile \
    -DcreateChecksum=$createChecksum \
    -DrepositoryId=$repositoryId \
    -Durl=$url
```