# I add dependency in pom.xml

Tags: xml, maven, software-distribution, artifact

I add dependency in pom.xml.But I got error in my pom.xml file Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.2.0.Is there any thing wrong in the steps I followed. Please help me out.

```
         <dependencies>
           <dependency>
          <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
          <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
          <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>   
               <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>   
               <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>   
               <version>4.0</version>  
               <scope>runtime</scope>  
          </dependency>             
       </dependencies>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Missing artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537396/missing-artifact-com-microsoft-sqlserversqljdbc4jar4-0)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Oracle **ojdbc** is not publicly available in maven repositories.
You should download it from the Oracle site, add it to your local repository manager and then it will be resolved by Maven.

If you don't use a repository manager (such as [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview)), look into it. It's the correct way to manage your maven environments.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> user3302059 asked:
>
> Is there any thing wrong in the steps I followed? Please help me out.

Technically speaking no, but there are [license constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository/23723203#23723203) which you should be aware of.

> Eldad AK answered:
>
> If you don't use a repository manager (such as Nexus or Artifactory), look into it. It's the correct way to manage your maven environments.

Generally speaking Eldad AK's answer is true, but [installing an Oracle Database JDBC Drivers to a repository manager cause a license violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository/23723203#23723203).