# Spring boot gradle cannot load sqlserver dependency

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I am trying to build a springboot application, with microsoft sql server connection. I build  connection to mysql and it worked fine, but now i cannot connect to my mssql database, because springboot gradle script doesn't load the **'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4'** jar. I tried to load the jar via gradle script in a non-springboot project and it worked fine. Is springboot doing something i don't know? Or is there another problem?

**My gradle-script:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'BEAT-Surflet'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-jms')
    compile('org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker')  
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Maybe the problem is, that springboot tries to load the version by himself or conflicting because of it. I tried to exlicit give him the version too (**'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0'**), but it didn't work either. So why my gradle-script or my springboot project doesn't load the mssql jar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537396/missing-artifact-com-microsoft-sqlserversqljdbc4jar4-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had simmilar issues. I Solved this by using net.sourceforge.jtds 1.3.1. driver. I suggest using this driver for MSSQL databases.
Microsoft driver is really bugged and it do not support of some widely used data types.

Comment: JTDS does not support some SQL Server types, like UniqueIdentifier, and IIRC it also does not support JDBC4? Either way, JTDS does not work for my project, I have to use the MS driver

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you really want Spring Boot, not Gradle, to be able to use MS SQL Server -- Gradle just puts the dependency on the classpath.

You may need to specify `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` in you application properties/yml file. See the [Working with SQL Databases](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) section of the documentation.

Good luck.

Comment: Nope, i really wanted gradle to load the mssql jar file.