# Maven Build - Couldn't resolve dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, maven-plugin, sqljdbc

**OS**: OSX Yosemite
**Eclipse**: Kepler
**Problems:**
1. [ from Eclipse Run ] : maven-compiler-plugin is missing
2. [ from Command Line ] : Failure to find com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:2.0

I have a maven project which pom.xml ( partly ) defined as mentioned below, after seeing the problem i manually executed `Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar` in the project directory where the pom.xml is defined and the result came as BUILD SUCCESS. However when i run maven build i get error [2]. and when i try to run in eclipse i get error [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537396/missing-artifact-com-microsoft-sqlserversqljdbc4jar4-0).

MVN:

```
mvn -version    
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T10:41:47-06:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
```

POM.XML:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId> 
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId> 
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
    <target>1.6</target>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <fork>true</fork>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Error 1:**

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for XXXXXXXXXX:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 139, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

**Error 2:**

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for XXXXXXX:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 139, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XXXXXX 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:2.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.381 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-15T20:04:48-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XXXXXX: Could not resolve dependencies for project XXXXXXXXX:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project XXXXXX: Could not resolve dependencies for project XXXXXXXXX:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
```

**Reference:**
I did refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537396/missing-artifact-com-microsoft-sqlserversqljdbc4jar4-0) post and couldn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlserver jar file needs to be added in the maven directory as mentioned below,

```
Path : /Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/sqlserver/sqljdbc4/2.0
File: sqljdbc4-2.0.jar
```