# How to connect sql server through java code?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, logic

I am creating application where I need to connect my services to sql server. When I run the test code after adding dependency, it runs successfully. This is the test code which runs successfully :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://10.235.5.38\\name;user=sa;password=password;database=dbname");
                Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
                 if (conn != null) {
                        DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
                        System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName());
                        System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());
                        System.out.println("Product name: " + dm.getDatabaseProductName());
                        System.out.println("Product version: " + dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
                    }
            }
    }
```

But when I add dependency for jdbc and run the same code while creating service , it gives me error like :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.zcon.vmh.dao.implementations.AdvisoryBoxDaoImpl.connectionTest(AdvisoryBoxDaoImpl.java:131)
    at com.zcon.vmh.services.implementation.AdvisoryBoxServiceImpl.connectionTest(AdvisoryBoxServiceImpl.java:19)
    at com.zcon.vmh.controller.AdvisoryBoxController.connectionTest(AdvisoryBoxController.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have added this dependency in pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

What changes I should make so that I can have connection successfully while creating service?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537396/missing-artifact-com-microsoft-sqlserversqljdbc4jar4-0/30111956#30111956

Comment: The scope is 'test', the dependency won't be visible in or packaged with the application when it runs normally, not as a test. Change it to "runtime".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency's scope is `test`, which means it will not be in the classpath when the application runs normally (not as a test). Change the scope to `runtime`, in which case classes inside the *.jar* will be available in run-time both if you run the application in the IDE or use a Maven plugin to package it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still facing the issue with maven , you can download sqlserver jar file separately and add it in your project and try to run again.below is the path to download jar file.

http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqlserverjdbcjar.htm

Comment: Thanks for your time Shrikant, replacing 'test' with 'runtime' solved the problem actually.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Microsoft doesn't make this artifact available via any maven repository . I would suggest you to use below dependency to resolve your issue

Microsoft has published some their drivers to maven central:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: The dependency was apparently downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774 and either added to a private Maven repository or installed locally using mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc42.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.2 -Dpackaging=jar