# Maven + SoapUI ClassNotFoundException(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)

Tags: maven, groovy, soapui, pom.xml

need a little bit of help with Maven and SoapUI. The long-term plan is to integrate my SoapUI tests with Jenkins, however, i'm unfortunately falling down at the first hurdle, when getting my tests to run with Maven. Whenever I run my SoapUI tests via maven on the command line I keep getting the following error:

> 2017-09-20 10:03:06,977 ERROR [errorlog]
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) at
>   groovy.sql.Sql.loadDriver(Sql.java:701) at
>   groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(Sql.java:483) at
>   groovy.sql.Sql$newInstance.call(Unknown Source) at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
>   at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:13) at
>   com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:100)
>   at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:154)
>   at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:239)
>   at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:52)
>   at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:152)
>   at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:47)
>   at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:139)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Now, As far as I'm aware I have included all the necessary dependencies. Here is a copy of my pom file. It's a simple one, I've borrowed from the internet and tweaked the usual bit.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.smartbear.samples</groupId>
<artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Maven 2 SoapUI Sample</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
            <outputFolder>logs</outputFolder>
            <printReport>true</printReport>
            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
              <projectFile>test-testing-test-Service-API-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
            </configuration> 
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.31</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>    
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>                             
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Can anybody spot any obvious mistakes I've made? have I missed something? Is there some setup/configuration I'm not aware of within Maven/SoapUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

he searches for sqlserver dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>{version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

but mysql dependancy found in pom file

Comment: I found some additional info on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537396/missing-artifact-com-microsoft-sqlserversqljdbc4jar4-0

Comment: you can alse use open sorce maven support  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2016/11/17/open-source-jdbc-maven/

Comment: @saab613, if that above answer resolves, then you should consider accepting it as answered.