# Spring 2.2.1 Build Error Missing artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-3

For the part of spring 4.1.7 to spring boot 2.2.1,i have added `spring-boot-starter-parent` in my parent project as given below.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>     
</parent>
```

when I tried to build my parent and child project, it getting an error

```
Missing artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0
```

[image]

.m2 folder structure

[image]

Am also refer the following link
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537396/missing-artifact-com-microsoft-sqlserversqljdbc4jar4-0/35914737)

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tied to delete `C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0` folder then rebuild the project .Now its working fine for me.