# Finding Maven command-line or shell using Eclipse Luna Maven plugin on Windows 7

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, eclipse-luna

First this question is not the same as "Setting up maven dependency for SQL Server". So I am a noob when it comes to Maven and Spring. I need to install the SQL Server JDBC drivers for my application, which I know would be best done using the Maven command line, specifically:

mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar" -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar

I do not know where or how to access a maven shell to enter this however. I am using the Eclipse Luna Maven plugin (m2e) on a Windows 7 system and have no idea how to get the Maven command-line/shell or what I might add to my path that would give me access; when I type mvn my system does not know what I am talking about. The maven eclipse luna m2e package is installed.

Again the question is NOT how to set things up. My question is how do I access the maven shell, given my setup? Where do I access the maven shell from? What do I add to my path to access maven in the command prompt?

Any insight would be much appreciated. And please before marking as already answered, make sure that it is, because people marked this as being answered by something that does not come close to answering this.

Comment: I think here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942407/setting-up-maven-dependency-for-sql-server

Comment: Right, I get that part, I just don't know where I can enter the Maven shell... mvn is an unrecognized by my system and I have no idea what to even add to my path that would give me maven command-line access.

Comment: This is not the same question as "Setting up maven dependency for SQL Server " at all, I know the answer to their question, my question is how to gain access to the maven command line, not what to type into it. Come on...