# Add external library .jar to Spring boot .jar internal /lib

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have an external .jar that cannot be imported from public repositories using pom.xml, it's `sqljdbc41.jar`.

I can run the project locally from my IDE, and everything will work. I referenced the library after downloading it like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc41</artifactId>
    <version>4.1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/sqljdbc41.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

When I run `mvn clean package` to create my .jar file and try to run the created .jar, a mistake will pop up, which mentions the SQL Server references are not valid. I then extracted my .jar file and true enough, everything that is referenced in the `pom.xml` file properly gets downloaded and added, however, my SQL Server does not.

I can, in a very hacky way* just manually add the `sqljdbc41.jar` to my /lib folder after it's been compiled as a .jar, and it'll work, however that seems highly unoptimal. What would be a better approach?

---

*Opening the .jar file with Winrar, going to the /lib folder, manually selecting my `sqljdbc41.jar` file, then make sure to select the No Compression option bottom left where Winrar gives you compression options, in case you find this by Google and no one answered.

Comment: I have tended to use Artifactory or Sonatype Nexus to store the Microsoft artifact. But my preference is to switch to JTDS: net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1 (there may be a newer version).

Comment: I have seen jtds, and would consider it were this a new project, but it's at this point a completely built application, so switching to JTDS is nonviable due to time constraints. 

I'll look into Artifactory/Sonatype Nexus though.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

you can set 'includeSystemScope' to true.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 34):

You could install the sqljdbc41.jar in your local repository :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/sqljdbc41.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc41 -Dversion=4.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

And then declare the dependency as a standard dependency :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>sqljdbc41</artifactId>
   <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you use a remote artifact repository (nexus, archiva...) you also need to deploy the artifact on this repository. You can find more here : https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Comment: This works, and bonus points for adding the remote information, I setup a nexus remote repo. and everything works great now. I also tried the local method and that worked as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a point - you might just want to check what the MS Licensing has to say about distribution. I have NOT looked myself, but MS has a history of...being difficult.

Answer (score 17):

Another way, you can put it into the resources folder, such as resources/lib/xxx.jar, then config the pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc41</artifactId>
    <version>4.1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/sqljdbc41.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

It works for me:

```
project {root folder}/libs/ojdbc-11.2.0.3.jar
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/ojdbc-11.2.0.3.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

When **Spring-Boot** projects are used with maven or gradle plugins they packaged the applicaiton by default as executable jars.
These executable jars cannot be used as dependency in any another **Spring-Boot** project because the executable jar add classes in ***BOOT-INF/classes*** folder. This means that they cannot be found when the executable jar is used as a dependency because the dependency jar will also have the same class path structure as shown below.

[image]

If we want to use project-A as a maven dependency in project-B then we must have two artifacts. To produce the two artifacts, one that can be used as a dependency and one that is executable, a **classifier** must be specified. This classifier is applied to the name of the executable archive, leaving the default archive for use as a dependency.
To configure a classifier of exec in Maven, you can use the following configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So the **MAJIC WORD** here is `<classifier>exec</classifier>` this will create a jar structure as below and then it could easily be conusmed by spring-boot project as maven dependency jar on class path.

[image]

The above plugin need to be add in project-A pom that is going to be used as dependency in project-B. Same is explained in spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-build) section 16.5. as well.

Answer (score 4):

In Spring Boot: I also faced similar issue and below code helped me.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can u pls also explain this approach, what it does

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the fault was providing a version number without "dot" in  tag:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>1</version>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

This one works:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to work through the local repository, the target .jar file that we will work with must be in the s2 folder. Several methods can be used for this:

1. The file can be taken manually and put in the relevant place (not
   preferred). The same process can be done by installing it via the
   console.
2. Relevant Remote URL is written in the .pom file dependencies and
   automatically places it in the s2 folder when Intellij is refreshed
   (validate) in the IDE used.
3. The same process can be done by addressing the .pom file dependencies via the centeral repository.

**Attention:** ComponentScan should not be forgotten for the related jar work on SpringBot.