# Build failure in Spring-boot-starter project due to missing WebApp libraries

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, maven-3, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a Spring-Boot-Starter-project in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0 and is trying to build a .war for deployment on an EC2 instance. I have added two jars to allow JDBC connectivity to PostgresSQL DB server from my deployed war.

[image: location of added jars in spring-boot-starter project]

I have also added the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` path to the project build path as shown below

[image: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib path is added to Java build path]

However, I am getting the Compilation error when I am doing `mvn compile` with a build failure stating the reason as unavailability of the jar classes

Any help will be really appreciated

[image]

Comment: You have to add dependencies in your pom file. If you are working with Maven you need to understand the truth is only in the POM not in your IDE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured Project build path in your eclipse, and it will not impact anything when you are doing `mvn compile`. Maven will not include the jar from the lib folder as it does not know lib folder's presence. You should apply either of below two options:

a. If those jars are present in maven repository then update your pom to read from maven repository directly.
b. Install these jars in your local repository then refer it in your pom.xml, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209982/3530898 for details

Comment: I installed the jars in local repo as you said and then added standard dependency in pom.xml. It worked like a charm. Thanks!