# How to pass external jar file to spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, war, executable-jar

I am creating spring boot restful application. This application uses external jar files.

When I create war file for application and deployed on local as well as server then this works fine.
But when I create executable jar file of this application this is not using external jar file.
I have class not found exception.

How Can I resolve this problem?

Anyone suggest me the way to pass external jar file for executing jar file.

Comment: what kind of external jar file are you dealing with. Can't you add this as a dependency in pom?

Comment: can you show your pom.xml file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add external library .jar to Spring boot .jar internal /lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207842/add-external-library-jar-to-spring-boot-jar-internal-lib)

Answer (score 1):

May be that could help

```
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>com.google</artifactId>
        <groupId>Ab</groupId>
        <version>0.0.4.3</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/Ab.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

This way you can add any jar file as a maven dependency.

Answer (score 1):

install your external jar using

```
mvn install:install-file
```

then provide it as maven dependency

```
<dependency>
        <artifactId>your-custom-jar</artifactId>
        <groupId>group.id</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>

</dependency>
```

and spring will package it in final executable jar

for more details on installing custom jar refer [this](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Fat Jar / Uber Jar / Shadow Jar/ [Shaded Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49811665/6785908) (whichever name you prefers) so that all your dependencies is wrapped inside the jar file. Here is an [article](https://www.baeldung.com/deployable-fat-jar-spring-boot) on how to do that for maven. [This](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar) is for gradle (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow).

### Gradle

**Using the plugins DSL:**

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "5.1.0"
}
```

**Using legacy plugin application:**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.1.0"
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
```

### Maven

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have to makes changes in pom file. This will solve my issue.

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

I just add this lines then my executable jar file works fine.

```
<configuration>
    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
    </configuration>
```