# Why my jar doesn't include the gurobi.jar?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gurobi

I wrote a rest APi with spring. Now i want to make a runnable jar, but one jar isn't included can someone tell me why.

That is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.21.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.40</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.roufid.tutorials</groupId>
            <artifactId>example-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>/home/mirko/Downloads/gurobi903/linux64/lib/gurobi.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
              <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>assemble-all</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>

            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gurobi</id>
            <name>Gurobi Jar</name>
            <url>http://maven.imagej.net/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>s</id>
            <name>Springs Mileston</name>
            <url>http://cogcomp.org/m2repo/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I run it via `mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage`
The code is running so i can run with `java -jar` but when i want to connect to my API, it says that the *gurobi.jar* is missing. When i go into the jar all the libraries are included only the *gurobi.jar* from my pom.xml is missing.

Comment: Your dependency of the gurobi.jar is in scope "system". Have a look here, to include these kind of jars : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43822161/13454816.
But it would better, if your libs is not referred per path. Maybe you should restructure your project into a multi-module product or install your dependency into your repository.

Comment: You don't need both spring-boot-maven-plugin and maven-assembly-plugin, the first one will do. Not sure if it will add the system-scoped dependency, though.