# How to add an external jar that's not published on Maven central to a gradle project

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management, artifactory

Microsoft doesn't publish its Sql Server jdbc drivers in Maven central; they're only available as a [download](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx) form msdn.

With Maven, one possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6983811/3199595) was to install the missing jar in Maven's local repository, but that has to be done separately on each machine, and it wouldn't work with a Gradle build that doesn't use the local Maven repository.

Is there a convenient way of placing the jar in the company's central artifactory repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it in artifactory 4.0.2:

Go to the "Artifacts" menu on the left, and click on "Deploy".
[image]

Pick "ext-release-local", and drag the jar into the box.

Fill in the regular Maven artifact details - group id (e.g. `com.microsoft.sqlserver`), artifact id (e.g. `sqljdbc4`) and version (e.g. `4.2`) and click on "`Deploy Jar's Internal POM/Generate Default POM`"

[image]

That's it! The jar should be available from artifactory with the group id, artifact id, and version you entered:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: '4.2'
}
```