# Getting null resultset working with hibernate and spring boot to connect to SQL Server 2012

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

Trying to connect to two databases - Informix and SQL Server 2012 from a single application. The code is working fine when connecting to Informix DB, but not working with SQL Server 2012.

Tried Criteria queries, Native SQL queries, HQL queries to select the data from SQL Server DB. Initially, did the dependency setup for SQL Server.
For setting the Sqljdbc Maven Dependency, I followed this:
[Missing artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537396/missing-artifact-com-microsoft-sqlserversqljdbc4jar4-0) and it is added without any issues. Tried other ways to add the dependency which can be found in
[Setting up maven dependency for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942407/setting-up-maven-dependency-for-sql-server)

Later, opened a session and created the query for retrieving data from SQL Server DB. But when trying to execute, getting a null resultset as output without any errors.

Tested a workaround of JDBC Connection to SQL Server and it worked fine. Got the data records, but not getting them when working with Hibernate

Thanks in advance..!!!